# Is there a WM that is more customizable than gnome but you do not need to configure from the scratch?

Tags: window-manager

Last weekend I installed awesome WM and I really think this name is a fair one, this WM is really awesome.
I liked how it felt efficient and customizable. I did not do anything special but I had the feeling I could be very efficient using it. After some hours tweaking it (theming, some keyboard shortcuts and things like this), I found out that many "basic" things was not provided out of the box:

- Multiple screen support (one should use `arand` to configure it and then import in the rc file)
- My keyboard screen brightness keys should be configured
- My keyboard media control keys were not configured
- A shutdown button in the ui
  And probably some other things that I did not have time to find out (I don't understand why Gnome is able to provide it out of the box and awesome WM is not).

I would not like to invest my time setting up things that are already provided somewhere else, therefore I ask: is there any WM that provides you more of-the-shelve basic features, but allow you more customization options than gnome? Something between awesome WM and gnome?

Thanks!

Comment: I would recommend to try Ubuntu MATE 20.04 LTS from live media first.

Comment: I had a similar experience with gnome: always felt I was fighting the system and the system was trying to control me rather than the other way round. I tried kubuntu and have not looked back; it is everything I was expecting when I switched to Linux, have neen using it since 18.04.